# What does the "Caution" box mean on the sectional near Half Moon Bay, California?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

What does this *Caution* box on the sectional chart near Half Moon Bay, California mean? Is there an official reference for the meaning of this box?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is a bit confusing and interestingly [there is nothing in the FAA's sectional guide on "Caution"](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/cug-complete.pdf) boxes although [they do appear on other charts as well](https://generalaviationnews.com/2014/08/14/vfr-sectional-theres-more-to-know/).

This one in particular is a warning that you will need monitor the radio for the transition routes below 2000 ft. If you can zoom in or get TAC level map resolution you will see a different warning

[image]

([source](http://vfrmap.com/))

If you note a bit south of half moon bay the chart makes note of the fact you should be using the TAC in that area:

[image]

([source](http://vfrmap.com/))

Comment: I already +1ed, but then noted the contact frequency is different than the 124.3. This [thread](http://www.vansairforce.com/community/showthread.php?t=153797) suggests it's a <2000 CTAF.

Comment: I don't think the answer is correct. Below 4,000-6,000 you are outside class B and you don't need ATC - it is a [VFR Flyway](https://skyvector.com/?ll=37.52078486007063,-122.4847021968532&chart=156&zoom=2). The VFR Transition Route is above 4,000-6,000.

Comment: @rvernica I read that as the flyway being "Below 6000 or Below 4000" depending on where you are, not above.

Comment: @Dave that is correct, the flyway is below and ATC clearance is not required on the flyway.

Comment: @rvernica is it just a monitor the frequency situation? Ill update the answer to be a bit more vague